# Yii2 JWT 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, yii2

Please help me in fixing this problem. I want to try sizeg/yii2-jwt (https://github.com/sizeg/yii2-jwt). I followed the Step-by-step usage example but I always get authorization issues. I also want to change the Model (I want to replace it with something other than the User model).

On Github it says after installing the plugin I have to edit web.php

```
'jwt' => [
            'class' => \sizeg\jwt\Jwt::class,
            'key' => 'secret',
            'jwtValidationData' => \app\components\JwtValidationData::class,
        ],
```

After that I should create JwtValidationData class. where you have to configure ValidationData informing all claims you want to validate the token:

```
class JwtValidationData extends \sizeg\jwt\JwtValidationData
{
 
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->validationData->setIssuer('');
        $this->validationData->setAudience('');
        $this->validationData->setId('4f1g23a12aa');

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

in the User model:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['id'] === (string) $token->getClaim('uid')) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And the controller:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller {
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => JwtHttpBearerAuth::class,
            'optional' => [
                'login',
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
    
    private function generateJwt($id) {
        $jwt = Yii::$app->jwt;
        $signer = $jwt->getSigner('HS256');
        $key = $jwt->getKey();
        $time = time();


        return $jwt->getBuilder()
            ->issuedBy('')
            ->permittedFor('')
            ->identifiedBy('4f1g23a12aa', true)
            ->issuedAt($time)
            ->expiresAt($time + 3600)
            ->withClaim('uid', $id)
            ->getToken($signer, $key);
    }

    public function actionLogin($person_id) 
    {
        $token = $this->generateJwt($person_id);

        return $this->asJson([
            'id' => $token->getClaim('uid'),
            'token' => (string) $token
        ]);
    }

    public function actionData() 
    {
        return $this->asJson([
            'success' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

I thought it was the same as the tutorial but I always get unauthorized. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just created a token for the user, but where you use that?
you have to send token as "Bearer" authentication in your header to achieve this goal if you want to authenticate the user by "JwtHttpBearerAuth" behavior.

otherwise, you have to login the user manually in your code.